# Error of Build&Run for Android in Unity3d

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine, apk, signing

I dont build&run my game for android device in unity. I have two error at console.

First one:

```
Installation failed with the following output: 
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

Second one:

```
Error building Player: UnityException: Unable to install APK!
Installation failed. See the Console for details.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It says you don't have enough room on your device. Delete some apps and try again.

Comment: why upvote this post? What is the value?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Bundle Identifier, this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the app you are trying to install is of the same name as an existing app previously installed. Sounds silly, but i had this issue. and It took me really long to find out.